# How can I transfer simple strings from my local HTML to my Swift-App?

Tags: javascript, swift, webview

I'm working on an Swift-App with a `WebView`. My aim is to transfer simple Strings between the App and the local `HTML` (it's embedded in my App-Project). 
With the use of `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript()` I was able to transfer simple strings from a `UITextField` at my app to my local `HTML`. I just call with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript()` a `JavaScript-function` from my `HTML` and transfer the String from my `UITextField` as a parameter at my `JavaScript-Function`.
Now I want to do the same but the other way around to get a string from my `HTML`. Has anybody an idea how I could do that?

Comment: evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName and reference to your div for example ... value